# How to check Subscription for AD User Using IF Statement

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been trying to get a script to check Azure AD for a user in a particular subscription and if so then continue, if not then terminate script.

I assume selecting subscription will specify which Azure AD to use

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "The Main Sub"
```

Then I would get use

```
Get-AzureRmADUser | fl
```

But that's where I get stuck, I get display name value and upn

Assign the UPN to variable

```
    $x = user01@outlook.com
    if ($x -eq $null) {
"User not valid" Exit 
}
    Else
{
Continue
}
```

The background is a User launches this script, it has to validate the user belongs to correct AD\Subscription, and then the script will continue, but then log on with User01@outlook.com

Please Help :)

Comment: this doesnt make sense, user belongs to Azure AD tenant, not subscription

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes Sorry, the user belongs to the AD Tenant and also the fact they are on the network and able to launch a script would suggest they have access, but this is just to validate they are, I suppose a better check would be to see if they're in the correct group to be able to launch a script. Would that be something like get-azurermaduser -upn user01@outlook.com and "usertype -eq 'member'"

Comment: sorry, but i do not understand what you are trying to achieve at all

Answer (score 1):

```
$upn = "user01@mydomain.com"
$user = Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $upn 
if ($user -ne $null) 
{
"User exists in Azure AD"
} Else {
"User not found in Azure AD"
}
```